# Stop docker container service when Go test fails

Tags: docker, go, jenkins, build, docker-compose

I'm running my Go tests using a docker-compose service. I want to fail the container or build when my tests are Failed. But now, when Go-tests are failed, docker container shows `pr_validator_tests_1 exited with code 0` which is not correct.

```
tests_1        | FAIL   go-testing-framework/tests  0.029s
tests_1        | FAIL
pr_validator_tests_1 exited with code 0
```

I'm running my docker-compose file using this command: 
`docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from test`

This is how I'm running my test suite.

```
func TestIntegration(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, new(TestSuite))
}
```

Test assertion:

```
if !s.Equal(expectedCode, response.StatusCode) {
        s.T().Error(message)
        return
    }
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  integration:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "localhost", "3000"]
    environment:
      - some envies
    container_name: integration
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  mockservice:
    image: mock:latest
    environment:
      - some envies
    ports:
      - 8801:8801

  tests:
    image: go-testing-framework:latest
    environment:
      - URL=http://integration:3000
      - and some envies
    links:
      - integration
    depends_on:
      - integration
      - mockservice
```

Is there anyway to FAIL the Jenkins build without using Jenkins plugins or using golang code?

Comment: could you provide `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: and how do you asset your test result? some example of test that should fail

Comment: everything looks correct. should be `exit code 1`.  could you try `s.T().Fatal(err)` just in case

Comment: also it is better to provide the entire test file to see chain of execution: suite -> particular test

Comment: also I run just with `docker-compose up --build  --abort-on-container-exit`

Comment: @SergiiGetman I have tried with `s.T().Fatal(err)` as well. But container is not Failing. Is there anyway to get `os.Exit(code)` from `suite.Run(t, new(TestSuite))`?

Comment: It should work like a charm withos os.Exit

Comment: yes. But I have no idea how to get the exit code. I want to do something like 
`code := suite.Run(t, new(TestSuite))` but it's not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208250/discussion-between-sanjx-and-sergii-getman).

Answer (score 0):

I have added `||exit 1` at the end of the make command and also added a shell script to retrieve the exit code.

```
#!/bin/bash
make test
status=$?
if [[ $status != 0 ]]; then
  echo "exit code for test: " $status
  exit $status
fi
```

And this script terminates the container if the test fails